# I am trying to ask an question and make the system store the answer to that question and print it in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to ask and answer the question "How old are you?" and then store the user's response to that question and print out the answer. Here is what I have done so far:

```
age = input("How old are you?")
print('How old are you?', word)
agea = input("sixty")
```

I cannot get it to store sixty and print it out as a word. I would like even better to not only do so but be able to store and print the age as a number. Thus far, the system only prints the answer:

```
    How old are you?
```

Please do what you can to help.

Comment: Could you give an example for each line if the program worked correctly?

Comment: I can't uderstand what you are trying to do can you please add some clarification please? And the variable `word` isn't defined

Comment: Your answer is stored in variable `age`, as per the first statement. Then you try to print an undefined variable `word`, while you should be printing `age`.

Answer (score 2):

So, just for adding you some explanations about your code:

```
age = input("How old are you?") # Read the input from the user and save it to the 'age' variable

print('How old are you?', word) # Print message, using 'word' as a variable. 
# This should throw an error message since 'word' is not assigned anywhere above.

agea = input("sixty") # Print the 'sixty' message, read the user input and save it into 'agea' variable. 
# What I imagine is that you have typing error here. Do you mean 'age' instead of 'agea'?
```

---

**Correction suggestion**

```
age = input("How old are you?") # Print message and wait for input from the user,
# assigning it to 'age' variable

print(f"You are {age} years old") # Print the message replacing {age} with the variable content.
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, there's no meaning to variable types like `word`. Numbers are whole or decimal, regardless of their size. There are some exceptions to that rule, but that is the general case. 
Now, to your question - the function `input()` can also print your string to the screen so the user can know he has to enter his input.

what you need to do in order to get the user's age and then print it is:

```
age = input("How old are you?")
print("you are ", age, " years old")
```

this will print the user's age. if you want to convert the input into an `int` just write

```
age = int(input("How old are you?"))
```

but be careful with this because if the user doesn't input an integer you will get an exception. In order to avoid that do:

```
age = input("How old are you?")
if age.isdigit():
    print("you are ", age, " years old")
    age = int(age)
else:
    print("you must input a number!)
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting a variable to an input, the value of the variable becomes what the user had input into the "How old are you? " statement.  In this case, if someone inputted "18" from the prompt, then `age` would equal `18` and it would print `You are 18 years old.`

```py
age = input("How old are you? ")
print("You are " + age + " years old.")
```

If you want the user to input a string such as "sixty" and have the result be something like `You are sixty years old.`, then you could make it so that the input value can only accept string values like so:

```py
age = input("How old are you? ")
if age.isdigit():
    print("Invalid")
else:
    print("You are " + age + " years old.")
    # or # print(f"You are {age} years old")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary, like this:

```
num2words = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine', 10: 'Ten', 
             11: 'Eleven', 12: 'Twelve', 13: 'Thirteen', 14: 'Fourteen', 15: 'Fifteen', 16: 'Sixteen', 17: 'Seventeen', 18: 'Eighteen', 
            19: 'Nineteen', 20: 'Twenty', 30: 'Thirty', 40: 'Forty', 50: 'Fifty', 60: 'Sixty', 70: 'Seventy', 80: 'Eighty', 
            90: 'Ninety', 0: 'Zero'}



def n2w(n):
        try:
            print (num2words[n])
        except KeyError:
            try:
                print (num2words[n-n%10] + " " + num2words[n%10].lower())
            except KeyError:
                print ('Number out of range')



if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = input("Type you age using numbers:")
    n2w(int(a))
```

In this case, i picked the number as a integer and transformed it in a integer. The input and output was:

```
Type you age using numbers:55
Fifty five
```